# Using HashSet with a user class Employee

Tags: java, set, equals, hashcode, hashset

I know this will sound a very dumb question, but I got confused after what I have known about `HashSet` and what I see when I execute below code.

I have an Employee class as follows (keeping only relevant piece of code):

```
public class Employee {
    //assume it has 3 variable name(String),salary(double) and id(int)
    //assume the constructor, getter-setters are there 

    //following is my equals and hashCode implementation
    public boolean equals(Employee e){
        return name.equals(e.name);
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Now I have following code which uses `HashSet` :

```
Employee e1  = new Employee("Abc", 2.0, 1);
Employee e2  = new Employee("abc", 3.0, 4);
Employee e3  = new Employee("XYZ", 4.0, 3);
Employee e4  = new Employee("Mno", 5.0, 2);
Employee e5  = new Employee("Abc", 77.0, 1);

Set<Employee> sEmp = new HashSet<Employee>();
sEmp.add(e1);
sEmp.add(e2);
sEmp.add(e3);
sEmp.add(e4);
sEmp.add(e5);

for(Employee e : sEmp){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

So I get all the objects data being printed on my console as :

```
Abc 77.0 1
Abc 2.0 1
Mno 5.0 2
XYZ 4.0 3
abc 3.0 4
```

AFAIK, the set does not allow duplicates and this duplicay will be check on `equals` (correct me if I am wrong).

Also, `HashSet` uses the `hashCode`, so in above case, it should not add the object `e5`. But it successfully adds that element to the set. This confused me.

(Please ignore if I have missed standards and all that stuff, I am trying to understand the concept/implementation).

**EDITED :** This may sound a dumb question, but I am preparing for certification ans was trying to see how stuff works.

Comment: From the Collection javadoc page.  _"Implementations are free to implement optimizations whereby the equals invocation is avoided, for example, by first comparing the hash codes of the two elements. "_

Comment: @ Abubakkar Rangara can you provide Employee constructor code also

Comment: @MSach its simple, but I got my answer from below, it was silly mistake from my side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're overloading `equals` rather than overriding it. Its parameter should be of type `Object`.

But also your `hashCode` is checking the `id` while `equals` is checking the `name`. They should probably be constructed from the same properties.

Answer (score 3):

This is standard example of why we should be using `@Override` annotation wherever possible.

If you would use this annotation with your `equals` method, you would be informed by compiler that you are not overriding `equals` method, because there is no `equals(Employe)` method in superclass, but `equals(Object)`. So you are *overloading* this method (you are creating additional method with different arguments).

Because of this HashSet is not using code of your `equals` method, but code from `equals(Object)` method inherited from `Object` class which just checks references equality:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some more code in equals methods. This will allow you to update the latest value for the employee id.

```
package com.test.day16;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * 
 * @author PradeepPadmarajaiah
 *
 */
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String empName;

    public Employee(int empId, String empName) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the empId
     */
    public final int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    /**
     * @param empId
     *            the empId to set
     */
    public final void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the empName
     */
    public final String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    /**
     * @param empName
     *            the empName to set
     */
    public final void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.empId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee employee = (Employee) obj;
        if (employee.empId == this.empId) {
            employee.setEmpName(this.empName);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Raj"));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Pradeep"));
        employees.add(new Employee(1, "Kumar"));
        employees.add(new Employee(2, "Chandan"));
        employees.add(new Employee(2, "Amitava"));

        System.out.println(employees);
    }
}
```

Check the line "**employee.setEmpName(this.empName);**" This will override the value of id. This means, empId 1 will have latest empName value as **Kumar**
Else, empId 1 will have empName value as **Raj** which was first assigned and it will not ovverride the value to **Kumar** after checking 
This work similar to the HashMap mechanism now.

**Code Result will be**
[Employee [empId=1, empName=Kumar], Employee [empId=2, empName=Amitava]]